# Recursion function to check if bit is set or not (1\0)

Tags: c, recursion, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I have this template and I need to fill the empty places, the function needs to return (count) the number of set (1) bits in a number (x)

**In this question, an int is 2 bytes aka 16 bits**

Template:

```c
int dlukim(int x, int n, int count)
{
    if (n > 16)
        (1); // return count;
    else
    {
        if ( (2) ) count++;
        (3);// n++; 
        dlukim((4), n, count) // x
    }
}
```

What's after the // is what I think should fill the empty space and I just don't know what to do on empty space number 2.

Comment: What is this function supposed to do? What are `x` and `n` used for? Can you give an example of how you would call this and what the expected return would be?

Comment: Indentation is quite important for people to be able to read and understand code. Please [edit] your question to properly indent the code.

Comment: I edited the post with more information now. I believe n is there to count how many bits we checked to know when to finish the program.

Comment: "*I believe n is there to count ...*": So you did not write that code? Maybe start reading on the theory of recursion first, then ask.

Answer (score 2):

This is quite contrived, but something like this:

```
int count_ones(unsigned int x, int count)
{
  /* Base case: zero has no further bits set. */
  if (x == 0)
    return count;
  return count_ones(x >> 1, count + (x & 1));
}

int main(void)
{
    const unsigned int x = 0xfeedf00du;
    printf("%u has %d\n", x, count_ones(x, 0));
    return 0;
}
```

Not sure about the `n` argument, could be used to track which bit to inspect but I optimized it out and always inspect bit 0, using right-shift between recursive steps to move all bits through that position.

I also switched `x` to `unsigned int` since that's more "clean" when caring about the bits in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I believe you're probably right but it has to be in this template I posted. It's part of a task I need to do

Answer (score 0):

So first of all, `int` is 4 bytes which are 32 bits. But for 16 bits integer the code should look like the following:

```
if (n > 16)
    return count;
else {
    if (x % 2 == 1) count++;
    n++;
    set_bits(x/2, n, count);
}
```

Dividing a number by 2 means moving it to the right side by 1 bit. If `x % 2` is `1` - the current bit is set, for example consider the decimal number `7` which is `111` in it's binary representation, `7 % 2 = 1` and `7 / 2 = 3` which is `11` in binary, and so on...